# Generate sentences based on user selection which contain 2 data

Tags: javascript

Thank you in advance for the help, I will like to generate a sentence base on user selection and each option contain 2 data (Data 1 and 2). This data is not visible to end user.

Below is my example:

Dropdown list:

Apple

1. Red
2. Sweet

Lemon

1. Yellow
2. Sour

Upon selection from the drop down list, it will generate a sentence below:

This fruit is "+data1+" in color & it taste "+data2+"

Please share with me an example so I learn from it. Also may I know what is the exact term for the above example I have ask.

Thank you in advance for the input and advise!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML. If the extra data isn't visible, where is it? You could do `<option value="Apple" data-colour="Red" data-flavour="Sweet">Apple</apple>`.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thanks for the input. How do I pull the data out to place in the sentence from data color and data flavor when user select option value apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't say how or if you are currently storing the extra data, but one way to associate data with elements such that it won't be visible to the user is to use [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```
<option value="Apple" data-colour="Red" data-flavour="Sweet">Apple</option>
```

You can retrieve the values using the [`.getAttribute()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) or using the [`.dataset` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (not supported in older IE).

In context:

```js
document.getElementById("fruit").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var message = ''
  if (this.value != "") {
    var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex]
    var colour = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-colour")
    var flavour = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-flavour")
    var message = "The " + this.value + " is " + colour + " and it tastes " + flavour + "."
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = message
})
```

```html
<select id="fruit">
  <option value="">[Please select a fruit]</option>
  <option value="Apple" data-colour="Red" data-flavour="Sweet">Apple</option>
  <option value="Lemon" data-colour="Yellow" data-flavour="Sour">Lemon</option>
  <option value="Grapefruit" data-colour="Orange and Pink" data-flavour="Terrible">Grapefruit</option>
</select>  

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: I can't seem test out your code in notepad ++ dunno where went wrong, I only see the dropdown list.

Comment: The JS code would need to be inside a `<script>` tag that appears after the `<select>` element. (Or if the script is before the element then you'd need to use a DOM Ready or window onload handler so that the JS shown doesn't run until after the element has been parsed.)

Comment: ty for the detail explanation, I did applied the script tag but still getting the drop down list only, no result shown (the sentence - "The " + this.value + " is " + colour + " and it tastes " + flavour + "." does not appeared)

Comment: Note that in the code I've shown it only outputs the result to the browser's console. If you open your browser's dev tools (click F12 in most browsers) and go to the Console tab, do you see either the sentence or some error message? (In the snippet any console log statement is automatically shown on-screen too, but they wouldn't do that in your real page. Where do you want the sentence to be displayed?

Comment: OIC! I just want it to display just below the drop down list.